# type mismatch in Rquantlib Bond.cpp

Tags: r, rquantlib

I've been tracing back through bond.cpp and find the following in FloatingBond() :

```
double dayCounter = Rcpp::as<double>(datemisc["dayCounter"]);
```

$\mathrm{datemisc[]}$ is passed (traced back to) from FloatingBond.default in bond.R as

```
dateparams=list(....
                dayCounter='Thirty360',
                ....)
```

which is a string, so I would assume that it would be a pointer to a string in c++.

Looking downstream to $\mathrm{dayCounter()}$ in util.cpp I see

```
QuantLib::DayCounter getDayCounter(const double n){
    if (n==0)
        return QuantLib::Actual360();
    else if (n==1)
        return QuantLib::Actual365Fixed();
    .......
}
```

So downstream agrees with the type passed but the upstream in bond.R seems incorrect. I do not see where the text string is translated into a double.

What am I missing?

Comment: I should add this is true for the other parameters in "dataparams", the functions expect doubles but I see string pointers passed.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have already figured out. It's very common in computer science that all the primary data types get converted into a string for interfacing. Rcpp simply did the conversion for you. You shouldn't worry about the conversion and just focus only on the algorithm.

Comment: this is not automaticly generated code. this is not an answer and it is wrong.

Comment: @terryleitch Maybe you can write your answer?

Comment: The conversion is performed by R code matchParams() which is in the bond.R source prior to calling the c++ code. It's confusing as the name is reused in the call (e.g. dateparams<-matchParams(dateparams) ) so when looking at the code above you see the character strings. Would be better if the result was assigned to something more meaningful like "mappedparams".

Answer (score 0):

The conversion is performed by matchParams() which is in the bond.R source prior to calling the c++ code. It's confusing as the name is reused in the call (e.g. dateparams<-matchParams(dateparams) ) so when looking at the code above you see the character strings. Would be better if the result was assigned to something more meaningful like "mappedparams".